# React native calendar missing day of the month

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wix/react-native-calendars/master/demo/calendar.gif

The gif abow show the content of react-native calendar.
As you can see, it's have only 5 line therefore some month will miss someday. is there anyway to make the row to 6?

Answer (score 0):

It will automatically add the 6th row if needed. try May 2020, it has the same scenario as you described, you will get 6 rows in this month.[image]

Comment: in my case, calendar is horizontal, and its not work. you can try 07-2020 and 08-2020

Comment: what happens if you render the calendar vertically? does it show 5 rows in this case as well?

Comment: im not try vertical yet cause some styling affect and it now show the calendar anymore. And im busy right now so no time to try. sorry...